# pip3 install face_recognition error [Windows]

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-building-your-own-face-recognition-system-to-creep-out-your-friends-df3f4c471d55. I was able to run the `pip3 install cmake` but not `pip3 install face_recognition` or `pip3 install dlib`. When executing those commands, i receive the following:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j6ri.png)

I already have Visual Studio Code 2020 with Python, C/C++ and Cmake extensions installed.
My python version is 3.8.5.

Comment: Python 3.8 is not stable yet. use python 3.7.6

Comment: Reinstalled to python 3.7 and this error shows:
Command "c:\users\ashsy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\ashsy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gzeij4um\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\ashsy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8lbpnf_0\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ashsy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gzeij4um\dlib\

Comment: did you added cmake to path.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work! Thanks for helping gulbaz khan. But I still don’t know what bug it is but this is what I did to make it work:

I had to install dlib manually into my desktop. There are a handful of repositories in github to find this.  From my command prompt, i accessed the directory which containts the dlib .whl file and ran that. Afterwards, i `pip install face_recognition` and everything has been installed!